# How to extract day of week from timestamp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dayofweek, sqldatetime

I am trying to extract the day of the week from a timestamp in SQL Server.
I am specifically looking for the SQL Server equivalent syntax to `EXTRACT`.
I want to count how many fields are in each day of the week.

This is how I would do it on BigQuery:

```
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM order_date ) as day,
    count(*) count_trips
FROM `sales.orders` 
group by EXTRACT (DAYOFWEEK FROM order_date)
```

Comment: When you read the SQL Server docs for DATETIME functions which ones did you find that might be helpful? Also what datatype is your timestamp column?

Comment: Take a peek into datename()   For Example:  Select datename(WEEKDAY,getdate())

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATE(timestamp))
```

example:

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, '2022/05/08 18:50:30');
Output: Sunday
```

P.S.
I am helping you the day part only considering you know the rest of your code. Feel free to reply this for exact query.